# FFmpeg help . Need to be able to zoom and pan on a video at specific points and then be able to zoom out and pan in a different area of said video

Tags: ffmpeg

We are currently working with a 4k video file, and we need to be able to zoom in and pan the x- and y-axis to specific areas at specific times in the video to then be able to once more zoom out and pan again to a different area on a 1280×720 canvas.

Smooth transitions to ease in/out between the two commands would also be preferable.

Comment: Interesting, I would also like to know, Maybe by using the crop video filter:
ffmpeg -ss 33:40 -t 30 -i input.mp4 -vf "crop=width:hight:x:y'' part3.mp4

Creating several video parts and then joining them together.